# How to add custom column to Custom post page list?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

[image]

Image should explain what I am trying to accomplish. I have no idea how to do this, is anyone familiar with this sort of work?

Custom event date will be a custom event meta box value that is part of the post type. I want the custom meta box to have a column like the taxonomy event essentials(as seen in the picture)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the hook [`manage_${post_type}_posts_columns`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_columns) which can be used to do just that.

Basic example:

```
function wpse188743_events_cpt_columns( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = array(
        'event_date' => __( 'Event Date', 'textdomain' ),
    );
    return array_merge( $columns, $new_columns );
}
add_filter( 'manage_events_posts_columns' , 'wpse188743_events_cpt_columns' );
```

To fill the column with the related content you additionally have to make use of the [`manage_posts_custom_column`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column) hook.

Basic example:

```
function wpse188743_event_column_data( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'event_date' :
            echo 'event date logic goes here'; 
            break;
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column' , 'wpse188743_event_column_data', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score -2):

Many thanks for the help. Only one thing, the `manage_posts_custom_column` has the same functionality as the `manage_${post_type}_posts_columns` so to use it would also be `manage_${post_type_posts_custom_column`.